# Tool to trace data transferred over https

Tags: https, fiddler, packet-sniffers

I wrote a tool which transfer data over https channel to server. Now it need to be verified what data I transferred is exactly right or not by testing team.

Is there any tool which will capture the data transferred by program over https. I am transferring data in xml format which in not encrypted.

I tried this with Fiddler but its unable to trace the data.

Any tool which you know?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the server's private key and are not using Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman cipher suites (those with EDH or DHE in their names depending on the configuration used), you should be able to look inside the SSL/TLS traffic using [Wireshark and its SSL mode](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL).

If you don't have the server's private key, you can try using a MITM proxy (in which case you will need to make your client trust its certificates), possibly one of these:

- http://mitmproxy.org/
- http://crypto.stanford.edu/ssl-mitm/
- http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/